# How to get the fragment that spawned a View?

Tags: android, fragment

LayoutInflater is a a really powerful tool that does really cool things; such as inflate a Fragment from a layout resource and properly handle its life-cycle. For example:

```
<fragment class="com.test.TestFrag".../>
```

when taking the above layout and running it through the LayoutInflater, you will get the view that is spawned by Fragment. You can then add this view to any ViewGroup and have an instance of a fragment running around that still follows the Fragment life-cycle. My question is, how do you get the parent Fragment from this created view?

Comment: If your fragment XML uses the `id` attribute, does `FragmentManager#findFragmentById()` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no mechanism, at run-time, for a fragment to know what ViewGroup is hosting it.  That said, since your class would be extending the base Fragment class, there's nothing to stop you from adding an instance variable to your Fragment to keep track of the ID of it's parent.  If your fragment is added into the view hierarchy with a FragmentTransaction, then you have to specify which container would host it, since FragmentTransaction::add requires the ID of the ViewGroup that will contain the fragment.  If you're adding it to the ViewHierarchy using the XML tag, I don't see why you need to determine its parent at run-time since it isn't being added dynamically anyways.